# default value with group by clause

Tags: sql, group-by

I want the default value with group by clause.

I tried with below query but not get success

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Sum(points)),0)  
   FROM Table1 
   group by PanelistID having PanelistID = 4310497
```

please do need full

Comment: which database are you using

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 4310497 AS some, ISNULL(MAX(Sum(points)),0)  
   FROM Table1 
WHERE PanelistID = 4310497
   GROUP BY  PanelistID
```

You can insert constant values in SELECT CLAUSE and it doesn't effect on GROUP CLAUSE

Comment: it is not allowing me to use aggregate function MAX to use with Group by Clause